# PHP How to get timestamp of day / hour from timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

I want to get a timestamp of the current hour and the current day. How I can do this?

I store a timestamp as a datetime in my database, so I want compare my data like this:

- How many records were inserted during the current hour
- How many records were inserted during the current day

Thanks for your help

Comment: use php `date` function `date('h',strtotime('your_timestamp'))` for hour and `date('d',strtotime('your_timestamp'))` for day

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mktime` function by passing only the details you want and 0 for others (like minutes and seconds)

```
int mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") [, int $minute = date("i") [, int $second = date("s") [, int $month = date("n") [, int $day = date("j") [, int $year = date("Y") [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )
```

Given that parameter list you'll have a code like

```
$timestamp = mktime(date("H"),0,0,date("n"),date("j"),date("Y"));
```